# Python Selenium - How to find element from span class

Tags: python, selenium

Code trials

```
signupButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@text='SIGN UP')]']")
```

HTML Code

```
<span data-v-cd127b42="" data-v-26890ad0="">SIGN UP</span>
```

[More HTML Code of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdH8m.png)

Comment: //span[text()='SIGN UP'] is the appropriate xpath.

Comment: i changed it to  
signupButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(), 'SIGN')]")
and it now works

Comment: Just a note on that it works for any element which has SIGN in it for it's text value but if there are no other values with that value you should be fine.